# JFrame equivalent for C# handle pointer

Tags: java, winforms, jframe, c#-3.0, win32gui

I am currently trying to port code from C# to java. In the C# code, the panel.handle part returns an intptr of the current panel. The intptr is then passed to a DLL method. The C# code is the following:

IntPtr Handle = Panel1.Handle;

The same DLL must be used. I have found something using Win32 and JNI but I have not understood how to use it. Does anyone know the java swing equivalent to this method?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at [this](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/test/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WindowUtilsTest.java) as reference

Comment: Thanks for the link. This helped me a lot to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the link in the comment and some other research I have managed to find the equivalent to the Handle property in c#. Here is what I have done to anyone who is facing the same problem:

```
    import javax.swing.*;

    import com.sun.jna.Native;
    import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;

    public class main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
           final HWND hwnd = new HWND(Native.getComponentPointer(jFrame));
           System.out.println(hwnd);
       }
    }
```

Please Note that this only works with windows machines since only windows have the concept of everything is a window and every window has a handle.